# D3 - How do I put x-axis value and labels between two ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

How do I put x-axis values and labels in between two ticks in a chart like the screenshot below?

[image]

Each tick represents the start/end date of a period interval (the week of the year in this case), and the dot and bar represent the values for the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - For a working code sample, please see my D3 block [here](https://bl.ocks.org/ecgan/6da307ac465745bfc801850f4c1b57c6).

---

First, the scale for the x-axis must be a [time scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time-scales):

```
    let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([domainStartDate, domainEndDate]);
```

In D3, each axis tick has a line element to draw the tick line, and a text element for the tick label (see [API reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#api-reference)). Once we understand this, the solution below would become clearer:

For each x value, we generate two ticks. The first tick represents the mid date of the period, and the second tick represent the end date of the period. Note that the end date of one period is also the start date of the next period. We will hide and display the tick lines and labels in alternate manner in the end.

```
    let tickValues = values
        .map((value) => [value.midDate, value.endDate])
        .reduce((acc, cur) => {
            return acc.concat(cur);
        }, []);
```

Next, we construct an axis generator using the `xScale` and `tickValues` above:

```
    let xAxisWeekGenerator = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickValues(tickValues)
        .tickSize(10)
        .tickPadding(5)
        .tickFormat((d, i) => {
            // specify the text label to be returned here.

            let index = Math.floor(i / 2);
            return values[index].Week;
        });
```

Call the axis generator on your svg:

```
    let xAxisWeekUi = svg.append('g')
        .attr('id', 'xAxisWeek')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(xAxisWeekGenerator);
```

By now, if you view the page in your browser, you will see duplicated x-axis tick lines and labels for each value.

[image]

We just need to apply some CSS class to hide and display the tick lines and labels in zig-zag alternate manner:

JavaScript:

```
    xAxisWeekUi.selectAll('.tick')
        .attr('class', (d, i) => {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                return 'tick midWeek';
            }
            return 'tick endWeek';
        });
```

CSS:

```
/* hide the midWeek tick line. */
#xAxisWeek .tick.midWeek line {
    display: none;
}

/* hide the endWeek tick label. */
#xAxisWeek .tick.endWeek text {
    display: none;
}
```

The final output where the x-value label is between tick lines:

[image]